# SDL_SetClipboardText does not add text to the clipboard

Tags: c, clipboard, sdl-2

there is a code:

```
void sdl() {
    char text[] = "texttext";
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == 0) {
        if(SDL_SetClipboardText(text) == 0) {
            printf("work");
        }
    }
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I looked at different implementations and did not find what I did not do what others did. I compile on linux. the code completes without errors, SDL_Init works.

Comment: Any reason why you don't check the return values from `SLD_Init()` & `SDL_SetClipboardText()`?

Comment: I fixed it, but I was sure that everything was working and I tested it just now, nothing has changed